# How can we display Federated Search results in Chat Bot message to have more than one search result displayed?

Tags: einstein-chatbot, federated-search, bot-apex-action

We are trying to display Federated Search results in Chat bot message.

However, message text is obviously limited and cannot display even one full search result.

[image]

For this case, Federated Search was implemented with Open Search example provided publicly by somebody https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/wp-json/opensearch/1.1/document.

Then an Apex class was added for Chat Bot Apex Action implementation.

```
public class FederatedSearchBlog {
    public class SearchTermInput {
        @InvocableVariable(required=true)
        public String term;
      }
  
      public class SearchResultOutput {
            @InvocableVariable(required=true)
            public String result;
          public SearchResultOutput(Blog__x blog) {
              result = blog.DisplayUrl + ' ' + blog.Title__c + ' ' + blog.Summary__c;
          }
      }

  @InvocableMethod(label='Get Search Results')
  public static List<SearchResultOutput> getSearchResults(
      List<SearchTermInput> terms
  ) {
      String term = terms[0].term;
        System.debug('term: ' + term);
      List<SearchResultOutput> results = new List<SearchResultOutput>();
  
 
      List<List<Blog__x>> blogs = [
          FIND :term RETURNING Blog__x (DisplayUrl, ExternalId, Title__c, Summary__c, Date__c)
      ];
      System.debug('blogs [0]: ' + blogs[0]);
      for (Blog__x blog: blogs[0]) {
          results.add(new SearchResultOutput(blog));
      }
      
 
    
        return results;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Now even though the action returns `List<SearchResultOutput>`, only the first result will be displayed by bot to the end user.

Since results can be assigned to a single String/Text variable only, but not to the list.

Which means the end user can only see one search result but not all search results.

Also the user cannot see the full result, but only chopped-off portion of it.

[image]
[image]

Is this possible to display the full list of found search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to display multiple results is question action with multiple dynamic choices.

Apex method should accept the list of input parameters even though actually this will be always a list with the only element and should return list of lists, even though the result would actually be list with the only inner list as outer list element.

```
public class AdvancedBlogFederatedSearch {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Advanced Search')
    public static List<List<Blog__x>> search(
        List<String> terms
    ) {
        System.debug('@@@ terms:' + terms[0]);
        return [
            FIND :terms[0] RETURNING Blog__x (DisplayUrl, ExternalId, Title__c, Summary__c, Date__c)
        ];
    }
}
```

Then, as previously, we will have one question action with empty list of static choices to grab the search term, then we can reiterate with a message displaying the search term entered, and then we can add a question with dynamic choices with source of Apex action type and the action to be `Advanced Search`

[image]

It is important to select `[System] Object (Object)` as expected `Entity Name` response format so that formula input box is available to set `{!Title__c} for {!DisplayUrl} on {!Date__c} with {!Summary__c}` as formatted text for displaying a choice option based on the external object fields.

[image]

Also, it is possible first to save the apex action results to variable

[image]

and the use `From List Variable` action type

[image]

The search result options can be displayed either as menu options

[image]

or as buttons

[image]